# How to add a background image on toolbar?

Tags: android, material-design, toolbar

I'm learning about material design in android.
I want make a `toolbar` with a background-image, but without Collapsing `Toolbar`. I wanna to set fixed background image.

I don't know how to do it
Any idea, help or clues?

[image: example]

Comment: use coordinate layout

Answer (score 3):

I just did below line and it works, have you tried yet?

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16){
        mToolBar().setBackground(imageDrawable);
    }else{
        mToolBar().setBackgroundDrawable(imageDrawable);
}
```

If you want to learn material design, my project is for you, have a look, hope it helps.

https://github.com/DanielShum/MaterialAppBase

Answer (score 2):

You can set background just in xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?actionBarSize"
    android:background="@drawable/white_gray_rect">

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Cordinator layout for this type functionality, try to use this link for guide [Handling Scrolls with CoordinatorLayout](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Handling-Scrolls-with-CoordinatorLayout)